# C# Android Lists Returning NULL - JSON API

Tags: c#, android, json

Im having a problem ..
If I use a string to display my JSON request

```
string json2 = @" {
""Summoner_Id"": [{
    ""name"": ""Fiora's Inquisitors"",
    ""tier"": ""GOLD"",
    ""queue"": ""RANKED_SOLO_5x5"",
    ""entries"": [{
        ""playerOrTeamId‌​"": ""585709"",
        ""playerOrTeamName"": ""AP Ezreal Mid"",
        ""division"": ""IV"",
        ""leaguePoints"": 61,
        ""wins"": 175,
        ""losses"": 158,
        ""isHotStreak"": false,
        ""isVeteran"": false,
        ""isFreshBlood"": false,
        ""isInactive"": false
    }]
 }]
 }";
```

I am able to deserialize..

```
  var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
  var s = root.Summoner_Id[0].queue.ToString();
```

Where  s  returns the value "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"

Now this is all great but the problem is that if I use my url to json..

```
   string url = "https://oce.api.pvp.net/api/lol/oce/v2.5/league/by-summoner/585709/entry?api_key=" + KEY;
    JsonValue json = await JSONAsync(url);


 private async Task<JsonValue> JSONAsync(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then try to deserialize..

```
 var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        var s = root.Summoner_Id[0].queue.ToString();
```

It throws an error :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here is my class.

```
public class Entry
{
    public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
    public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
    public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    public int losses { get; set; }
    public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
    public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
    public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
    public bool isInactive { get; set; }
}

public class SummonerId
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tier { get; set; }
    public string queue { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<SummonerId> Summoner_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Have you compared the JSON string you download vs the hard coded string you used for testing? Are they identical?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RootObject
{
[JsonProperty("585709")]
public List<SummonerId> Summoner_Id     { get; set; }
}
```

This solved my problem.
The RootObject was a number which was causing errors.
Thanks David !